# Se ha denegado el permiso para el archivo adjunto

Tags: android-studio, archivo, gmail

buenas a todos.
Estoy haciendo una app que su única finalidad es un contador (con persistencia de datos SQLite). En una de sus funciones, es enviar un fichero con un registro de cuanto y cuando se a sumado o de lo que se ha restando.
Ya anteriormente, he creado el fichero y se ve que esta rellenado. Este es el codigo para hacer el Intent.

//MainActivty.tabla_actual = Variable Estatica.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                "mailto", "", null));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "HCB Counter - "+MainActivity.tabla_actual);
        File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile()+"/registro.txt");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, registros.getText().toString());

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, null),0);
```

[image: Lo que hay en el archivo]

[image: Para que veais que se encuentra ahí]

[image: Y obviamente, en el manifest]

Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso debes copiar el archivo a el directorio de almacenamiento externo para poder anexarlo ya que por restricciones de seguridad no podràs anexarlo obteniendolo directamente del directorio interno.

te sugiero usar un método para realizar la copia del archivo :

```
   private File exportFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {

        if (!dst.exists()) {
            if (!dst.mkdir()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        FileChannel inChannel = null;
        FileChannel outChannel = null;

        try {
            inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
            outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Exportar : " +e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        } finally {
            if (inChannel != null)
                inChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null)
                outChannel.close();
        }

        return dst;
    }
```

y usarlo para obtener el archivo y anexarlo para su envio

```
    //Obtiene ruta de archivo en directorio de almacenamiento interno.
    File fileInternal = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile()+"/registro.txt");
    //Obtiene ruta de archivo en directorio de almacenamiento externo.
    File archivoDestino = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "android" + File.separator+"datos");
    //copia archivo.
   File file = exportFile(fileInternal, fileExternal);

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Comment: Me da error en esta linea del metodo. 
`outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();`

Comment: 04-30 09:36:47.608 3280-3280/com.example.happyboxcontador E/TAG: Exportar : /storage/emulated/0/android/datos: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Comment: La solucion seria crear un archivo dentro del atributo `archivoDestino`?

Comment: @Sackmike crear una copia de tu archivo pero en el directorio Externo, este si te permitiría anexarlo.